# IdenitityServer4. How to create an access token from within login page?

Tags: identityserver4

I have created an IdentityServer application using IdentityServer4 with my own login page. When the user logs in (or fails to log in because of invalid credentials) I need to create an audit log record of that interaction. My system has a separate web service that handles audit logging. In order to call that service from my login page in my IdentityServer instance I need an access token. Is there a class/method somewhere in IdentityServer4 that I can just call to create an access token? It seems kind of overkill to make a web service call to the token end point in my application instance in order to get the token.

I.e. my IdentityServer application needs to be able to create access tokens for external clients, but it also needs to be able to create them for it's own use to allow it to be able to call an external service like audit logging.

Or am I looking at things all wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Simply inject 'IdentityServerTools' into your class this has the necessary APIs.

Comment: Once again. No documentation and no example provided.

Comment: because you ask so nicely everywhere - http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/topics/tools.html

Comment: Thank you once again. Btw I'm unable to upvote until the answer gets edited. Once it is I will.

Answer (score 0):

The class that creates the access token is `DefaultTokenService` and it has an accessiblity level of `public`.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Services/DefaultTokenService.cs

The relevant method is:

```
public virtual async Task<Token> CreateAccessTokenAsync(TokenCreationRequest request)
```

So it seems to be possible.

--

*Or am I looking at things all wrong?*

I'd probably defer the product owners on that one.

--

But I do find it ironic that you could

1. Register the IdentityServer as a Client using the client_credentials grant type and allow it access to your Audit Logging Api Resource.
2. Have the IdentityServer Client obtain an access_token from itself
3. And then make a call as the IdentityServer Client to Audit Logging Api Resource, which would then turnout around and call back to IdentityServer to validate the access_token it just generated.

That is way other Clients work, so why not itself...

**EDIT**

Just for documentation, here's what I have based on leastprivilege's instruction:

```
public AccountController(
    IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
    IClientStore clientStore,
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
    ITokenCreationService tokenCreationService,
    TestUserStore users = null)
{
    _users = users ?? new TestUserStore(Config.Users);
    _interaction = interaction;
    _account = new AccountService(interaction, httpContextAccessor, clientStore);
    _identityServerTools = new IdentityServerTools(httpContextAccessor, tokenCreationService);
}
```